# Function render datatables to send data-* html?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have some problem in datatbles render function.

```
$('#msidang-proposal').DataTable({
                "ajaxSource": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>mhs/get_msidang_proposal",
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "jenis" },
                    { data: null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                        return '<a href="'+data.link+'" target="_blank" />'+data.nama_file+'</a>'
                    } },
                    { data: null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                        return '<button class="w3-blue-grey control" data-set="edit_dokumen">Edit</button>'
                    } }
                ],
                "ordering": false,
                "searching": false,
                "paging":   false
            });
```

Problem is data-set not be read, and when i click it not event happen.
Somebody any solution? thanks.

Comment: Take a look at your code again. You have `data: null` but it seem not to be what the code itself expect.

Comment: I have changed to not null and the problem remains unresolved